# Why I am not getting error in following code?

Tags: c++, keyword

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    float data_member;
public:
    A(int a);
    explicit A(float d);
};


A::A(int a)
{
    data_member = a;
}

A::A(float d)
{
    data_member = d;
}

void Test(A a)
{
    cout<<"Do nothing"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test(12);
    Test(12.6); //Expecting a compile time error here
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting a error int this case as my CTOR that takes float value is explicit. But I am not getting any error in VS 2010. Please point me out if I am wrong with my understanding of keyword "EXPLICIT" in c++.

Comment: To understand usage of explicit keyword read:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: @AayushiJain Thanks for the comment but I have already gone through this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
explicit A(float d);
```

Does not do you think it does. It disables the implicit conversion from `float` to the type `A`. In short, It disables any implicit conversion wherein a float will be implicitly converted to a object of `A`. For ex:

```
void doSomething(A obj){}

doSomething(2.3);
```

It does not disable any implicit conversions allowed by the standard.

---

> **Why does it compile?**

```
Test(12.6);
```

Because the `float` parameter is implicitly converted to `int`. What happens behind the scenes is same as:

```
float a = 12.6;
int   b = (int)a;
```

Further, the conversion constructor `A::A(int a)` is used to create a object of type `A` which is passed to the method `Test()`.

---

> **Why does it not compile if you remove the `explicit`?**

Without the keyword `explicit` the conversion constructor `A::A(float d)` is available for conversions and this creates a ambiguity because there are two possible matches, when converting `12.6` to object of type `A`:

```
A::A(int a)
```

or

```
A::A(float d)
```

Since none scores over other in terms of best match, the compiler emits the diagnostic of ambiguity.

Comment: But how I am getting a compile time error for 2nd line in main function.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay by removing explicit, you can get compile time error

Comment: @ling.s then what is the use of explicit keyword. As far as I know explicit keyword should be used to disable implicit conversion. My aim is not to make this code compilable, but to understand the usage of explicit keyword.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay, With no explicit, it can either do an implicit standard conversion to `int` or to `float`. Both are equally valid, so overload resolution will fail. With the `explicit` there, it can only go for the `int` one implicitly. As for what it's good for, imagine a function taking a `std::vector`. Now imagine you call it with an argument of 3. If the size constructor was not explicit, that would be really unintuitive for it to compile like it would.

Comment: @Alok Save So if I make my CTOR A::A(int a) as explicit then the compilation will not go through. And currently the code is compiling because the float is first converted to int and then compiler is calling A::A(int a).

Comment: @Apoorvasahay: If you declare both conversion constructors as `explicit`, there is no conversion available from `float` to `A`, hence you will get a error. If you declare float version as `explicit` then implicit conversion from `float` to `int` takes place and then `int` version of constructor is used.